# Getting postal_code value from JSON results

Tags: json, google-maps, geocoding

I'm working with the Google Maps Geocoder. I've got everything working fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to 'traverse' (parse?) the JSON results.

How can I get the postal code from the Geocoder's JSON results?

My attempt as been to loop through 'address_components', testing each "values" key for an array containing "postal_code".

So here's a snippet of what I've written so far:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ address : cAddress }, function(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
            var fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
        var contactLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;

        var postalCode = $.each(results[0].address_components, 
                function(componentIndex, componentValue) {
                    var typesArray = componentValue.types;
            if ($.inArray("postal_code", typesArray)) {
                return componentValue.long_name;
                    }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The problem specifically is `postalCode` is

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],  
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`
```

Obviously, there is something I'm missing.

For reference, here is the link to Google Maps Geocoder JSON results:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

Thanks for any help!
~Amos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also note, "return" doesn't work. It's a asynchronous function. So by the time your function runs, the parent function has finished.

```
$.each(results[0].address_components, function(componentIndex, componentValue) {
     if ($.inArray("postal_code", componentValue.types)) {
           doSomeThingWithPostcode(componentValue.long_name);
     }
});
```

So your function must do something explicitly with the result. for example...

```
function doSomeThingWithPostcode(postcode) {
     $('#input').attr('value',postcode);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... asynchonous was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$` here is jQuery object, you are geting back the `results[0].address_components` collection, since your `return componentValue.long_name;` is ignored by `each()`. What you are looking for is `$.map()`, which will return modified collection.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me say thanks for this. Just helped me out of a jam myself. I did, however, have to alter the code a little bit.

The issue I had was that jQuery.inArray() does not return a boolean value - it either returns the element's index in the array or -1. I got confused with this, and I couldn't get your code to work without changing the if statement to read as such:

```
if( $.inArray( "postal_code", typesArray ) != -1 ) {
    pc =  componentValue.long_name;
}
```

When I had it set to check for true or false, the code within that if block would run on every single iteration of the $.each() loop, because the if statement would always return -1 instead of 0 or false. After checking if the $.inArray() method returned -1 or not, the code worked swimmingly.

Thanks again!